# Phpmailer sends mail with form errors

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have searched the internet for many hours. My Phpmailer works great but, it sends the email even if the form has errors, like if the email is take. I can't get it to know if the form has errors. Do I need to also query the database in my Phpmailer file or can I use the query return already done in my PHP register query?

In my register PHP query I check for if email is taken. If the email is taken the form displays an error, but PHPmailer sends the email even with the email taken error. How can I stop PHPmailer form sending an email with form errors. 
Notice my variable $user holds the check if email is taken return. How can I get PHPmailer to also use the variable $user?

```
   <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(array_key_exists("first",$_POST) && $_POST["first"] != "" && array_key_exists("last",$_POST) && $_POST["last"] != "" && (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) and PHPMailer::validateAddress($_POST['email'])) && array_key_exists("unit",$_POST) && $_POST["unit"] != "") {


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'gator*****hostgator.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '***********.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '*********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('admin********.com', 'Admin');
    $mail->addAddress('admin*****.com', 'HP Website');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);               // Name is optional
//    $mail->addReplyTo($email);
//    $mail->addCC($_REQUEST['email']);
//    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
//    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$bed = $_REQUEST['bed'];
$bath = $_REQUEST['bath'];
$web = $_REQUEST['web'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$manage = $_REQUEST['manage'];
//$unit = $_REQUEST['unit'];
//$uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$ck = $_REQUEST['rent'];
    //Content
    $mail->addEmbeddedImage('img/logo4.png', 'logo');
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Your HP unit is signed up';
//    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
//    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
//    $license_type = $_POST['license_type'];

$mail->Body    = '<p style="background-color:#333; color:orange; text-align:center; font-weight:bolder">Welcome to the HP Owner website</p>
<p style="text-align:center; margin:0"><img src="cid:logo"></p>
<p><strong>Name: </strong>'.$first.' '.$last.'</p>
<p><strong>Email: </strong>'.$email.'</p>
<p><strong>Unit#: </strong>'.$unit.'</p>
<p><strong>Bed: </strong>'.$bed.'</p>
<p><strong>Bath: </strong>'.$bath.'</p>
<p><strong>Website: </strong>'.$web.'</p>
<p><strong>Phone: </strong>'.$phone.'</p>
<p><strong>Management: </strong>'.$manage.'</p>
<p><strong>Show on HP website - (1 means show): </strong>'.$ck.'</p>

<p>If any of your info above is wrong, login with your username and password. Click on Update My Unit button and update your info..<br>
<br>If you checked the box Show On Rental Site, your unit will show - refresh the rental site or go to http://www.*********.php<br>
<br>If you need to delete everything and start over - contact the admin email admin***********.com';
$mail->AltBody = 'HP Owner Web Site - You are signed up';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
}
?>
```

AND MY PHP query

```
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
  //include_once 'mailer0.php';
    include_once 'includes/mailer.php';



  // Init vars
  $first = $last = $email = $unit = $bed = $bath = $web = $phone = $manage = $pwd = $confirm_password = $ck = '';
  $name_err = $unit_err = $bed_err = $bath_err = $phone_err =  $email_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = '';
  // Process form when post submit
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // Sanitize POST
    $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Put post vars in regular vars
    $first =  trim($_POST['first']);
    $last = trim($_POST['last']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $unit = trim($_POST['unit']);
    $bed = trim($_POST['bed']);
    $bath = trim($_POST['bath']);
    $web = trim($_POST['web']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $manage = trim($_POST['manage']);
//    $uid = trim($_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $ck = trim($_POST['rent']);
    // Validate email
    if(empty($email)){
      $email_err = 'Please enter email';
    } else {

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM condos_hp WHERE user_email=?");
if($stmt->execute([$email]));{
$user = $stmt->fetch();
}
if ($user) {

    // email found
    $email_err = 'Email is already taken';

}
      unset($stmt);

    }
    // Validate name
    if(empty($first) || empty($last)){
      $name_err = 'Please enter name';
    }
    // Validate name
    if(empty($unit)){
      $unit_err = 'Please enter your unit #';
    }
    // Validate name
    if(empty($bed) || empty($bath)){
      $bed_err = 'Please enter bed/bath #';
    }
    // Validate name
    if(empty($phone)){
      $phone_err = 'Please enter your phone';
    }
    // Validate password
    if(empty($pwd)){
      $password_err = 'Please enter password';
    } elseif(strlen($pwd) < 6){
      $password_err = 'Password must be at least 6 characters ';
    }
    // Validate Confirm password
    if(empty($confirm_password)){
      $confirm_password_err = 'Please confirm password';
    } else {
      if($pwd !== $confirm_password){
        $confirm_password_err = 'Passwords do not match';
      }
    }
    // Make sure errors are empty
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
      // Hash password
      $pwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      // Prepare insert query
//      (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_unit, user_bed, user_bath, user_web, user_phone, user_manage, rent)
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO condos_hp (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_unit, user_bed, user_bath, user_web, user_phone, user_manage, user_pwd,  rent) VALUES (:first, :last, :email, :unit, :bed, :bath, :web, :phone, :manage, :pwd, :rent)';
    //  $sql = 'INSERT INTO condos_hp (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :password)';
      if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind params
//        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last', $last, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':unit', $unit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':bed', $bed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':bath', $bath, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':web', $web, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':manage', $manage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rent', $ck, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        // Attempt to execute
        if($stmt->execute()){

          // Redirect to login
        header('Location: login0.php');
        } else {
          die('Something is not right');
        }
      }

      unset($stmt);
    }
    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
  }

?>
```

UPDATED CURRENT CODE.......

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Include db config
require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
//include_once 'mailer0.php';


// Init vars
$first = $last = $email = $unit = $bed = $bath = $web = $phone = $manage = $uid = $pwd = $confirm_password = $ck = '';
//$name_err = $unit_err = $bed_err = $bath_err = $phone_err = $email_err = $uid_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = '';

//$error = isset($_SESSION['error']) ? $_SESSION['error'] : [];

// Process form when post submit
if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
//  $error = array()
    //($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
//  echo var_dump($_POST);
//    echo '<br/>';
//       print_r($_POST);
//$error = ($_SESSION['error']);
    // Sanitize POST
//    $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $error = array();
    var_dump($error);
    if (!empty($error)) {
        echo "not empty";
    } else {
        echo "empty";
    }
    // Put post vars in regular vars
    $first = trim($_POST['first']);
    $last = trim($_POST['last']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $unit = trim($_POST['unit']);
    $bed = trim($_POST['bed']);
    $bath = trim($_POST['bath']);
    $web = trim($_POST['web']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $manage = trim($_POST['manage']);
    $uid = trim($_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $ck = ($_POST['rent']);

    // Validate email
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter email";
    } else {
// check if email is taken
        /*$sql = 'SELECT * FROM condos_hp WHERE user_email = :email';
        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
          // Bind variables
          $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          // Attempt to execute
          if($stmt->execute()){
            // Check if email exists
            $user = $stmt->fetch()
            if ($user){
              $email_err = 'Email is already taken';
            }
          } else {
            die('Something went wrong');
          }
        }*/
        /*$sql= "SELECT * FROM condos_hp WHERE uid = :uid";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
        //$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT uid FROM condos_hp WHERE uid=:uid");
        //$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$user = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //print_r($stmt->fetchObject())
        //$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($user) {
            // email found
            $uid_err = 'UserID is already taken';
            echo var_dump($user);*/

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT uid FROM condos_hp WHERE uid=?");
        $stmt->bindValue('1', $uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($user) {
            // $error[] = 'sorry username already taken !';
            // email found

            $error['uid'] = "user ID already taken";
//         die;
            //       header('Location: register.php');
            print_r($user);
            //      print_r($error);

            //} else { // or not die('Something went wrong'); }
        } else {

//   echo 'user does not exist<br>';
        }

        unset($stmt);
    }
    // Validate name
    if (empty($first) || empty($last)) {
        $error['name'] = "Enter name";
    }
    // Validate name
    if (empty($unit)) {
        $error['unit'] = 'Please enter your unit #';
    }
    // Validate name
    if (empty($bed) || empty($bath)) {
        $error['rooms'] = 'Please enter bed/bath #';
    }
    // Validate name
    if (empty($phone)) {
        $error['phone'] = 'Please enter your phone';
    }
    //Check phone # format 000-000-0000
    if (!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone)) {
        $error['phone'] = 'Please enter correct phone format';
    }
    //Check manage format
    if (!preg_match("/^(\s\(([^)]+)\))?[[:punct:]]?\p{Lu}+(?:[\s'-]?[\p{L}\d]+)+(\(([^)]+)\))*$/", $manage)) {
        $error['manage'] = 'Please enter correct management format';
    }

    //Check password format 4 and 8 digits long and include at least one numeric digit.
//    if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$/", $pwd)) {
//    $password_err = 'Password must be at least 4 digits with 1 number ';
    if (empty($uid)) {
        $error['uid'] = 'Please enter uid';
    }
    // Validate password
    if (empty($pwd)) {
        $error['pwd'] = 'Please enter password';
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$/", $pwd)) {
        $error['pwd'] = 'Password must be at least 4 digits with 1 number ';
    }

    // Validate Confirm password
    if (empty($confirm_password)) {
        $error['pwdpar'] = 'Please confirm password';
    } else {
        if ($pwd !== $confirm_password) {
            $error['pwdpar'] = 'Passwords do not match';
        }
    }
    // Make sure errors are empty
    if (empty($error)) {

        // Hash password
        $pwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // Prepare insert query
//      (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_unit, user_bed, user_bath, user_web, user_phone, user_manage, rent)
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO condos_hp (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_unit, user_bed, user_bath, user_web, user_phone, user_manage, uid, user_pwd,  rent) VALUES (:first, :last, :email, :unit, :bed, :bath, :web, :phone, :manage, :uid, :pwd, :rent)';
        //  $sql = 'INSERT INTO condos_hp (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :password)';
        if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            // Bind params
//        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':last', $last, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':unit', $unit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':bed', $bed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':bath', $bath, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':web', $web, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':manage', $manage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':rent', $ck, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            // Attempt to execute
            if ($stmt->execute()) {

                // Redirect to login
                header('Location: register.php');
            } else {
                die('Something is not right');
            }
        }

        unset($stmt);
    }
    // Close connection

    unset($pdo);
}
//include_once 'includes/mailer.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style.css">
    <title>Register HP Account</title>

    <script>
        function validate(form) {
            fail = validateFirst(form.first.value)
            fail += validateLast(form.last.value)
            fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)
            fail += validateUnit(form.unit.value)
            fail += validateBed(form.bed.value)
            fail += validateBath(form.bath.value)
            fail += validateWebsite(form.web.value)
            fail += validatePhone(form.phone.value)
            fail += validateManage(form.manage.value)
            fail += validateUid(form.uid.value)
            fail += validatePassword(form.pwd.value)


            if (fail == "") return true
            else {
                alert(fail);
                return false
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="includes/validate_functions.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">

        <h2 style="text-align:center">HP Sign-Up Form</h2>
        <p style="text-align:center">Fill in this form to register</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="first">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['name'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($first); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['name']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['name'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($last); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['name']; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['email'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['email']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="unit">Unit #</label>
                    <input type="text" name="unit"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['unit'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($unit); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['unit']; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <label for="bed">Bed</label>
                    <input type="text" name="bed"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['rooms'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($bed); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['rooms']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <label for="bath">Bath</label>
                    <input type="text" name="bath"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['rooms'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($bath); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['rooms']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="web">Website</label>
                    <input type="text" name="web" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($web); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="phone">Phone - 000-000-0000</label>
                    <input type="text" id="yourphone2" name="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890"
                           pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['phone'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($phone); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['phone']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="manage">Management - (VRBO, SELF, etc.)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="manage"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['manage'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($manage); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['manage'] = 'Please management'; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="uid">UserID - 8 length</label>
                    <input type="text" name="uid"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['uid'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($uid); ?>" placeholder="6 chars ex.betty12">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['uid']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="pwd">Password - min 6 digits</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['pwd'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($pwd); ?>"
                           placeholder="6 to 8 digits include 1 num - ex.1234, absd12">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['pwd']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password"
                           class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($error['pwdpar'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                           value="<?php echo htmlentities($confirm_password); ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['pwdpar']; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rent" value="0">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="rent" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"
                           checked="checked">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check to show on the rental site</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="register" name="register" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <a href="login0.php" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Have an account? Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery-input-mask-phone-number.js"></script>
<script>
    //xxx-xxx-xxxx format code
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#yourphone2').usPhoneFormat({
            format: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
        });
    });
</script>
<?php require_once './includes/footer.php'; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to complete your validation successfully before calling your email code. If you send it before you check the data, of course you'll get errors!

Comment: Synchro how do you delay the email code? Put the include file at the very bottom?

Comment: Put it inside a condition check so that it's only run if it succeeds: `if ($validationok) {//email code here ...`.

Comment: Synchro I've combed through most all PHPmailer threads on this forum and I see you maybe the most knowledgeable on PHPmailer code and your help is respected. 
I'm not sure how to condition all my form validations? Should I, if condition to the validation error messages? Can you expand on your condition check example? Like - // Make sure errors are empty
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err && empty($phone_err)){ $mail->send();}
I'm trying!

Comment: This isn't really a PHPMailer question - it's just general coding. I'd recommend assembling your errors in an array, like `$errors['name'] = 'Enter your first and last names';` as you check each condition, then later on check `if (empty($errors)) {...`, rather than having all those separate error variables.

Comment: I'm still a green horn at PHP and it's coming together. I think you mean change the long error array in my register.php as I noted above to your noted array example and place the if (empty($errors)) {... in my PHPmailer code.

Comment: Yes - think about it at a higher level - you have two main tasks, validation and sending email; do the validation first, and only if that works, run the email sending code.

Comment: I'm working and testing. Thanks Synchro

Comment: Synchro - I'm not having any luck. created error array $error = array(); and on all my validations I added $error['name'] = 'name must be entered'; My error array is always empty array(0) { } emptyArray. I can't get my error array to catch errors. I'm about to throw everything in the lake, it's driving me crazy. This is my only hang-up to finishing this project. Can you please help??? UPDATED CODE ADDED ABOVE

Comment: I reformatted your code to make it more readable. At the point you're `var_dump`ing `$error`, you've only just defined it so it will always be empty. Try moving that down to *after* you've applied all your validations. One other tip - use an IDE and learn how to use a debugger; There are some great free ones (NetBeans, Microsoft VS Code) and paid ones (PHPStorm).

Comment: Synchro - that worked! My error array is populating. Now I can't seem to get the error array to populate in my PHPmailer code. Tried $error = []; in PHPmailer and $error = isset($_SESSION['error']) ? $_SESSION['error'] : []; in the register code.
How do I get the error array over to the PHPmailer? Thanks for the HELP!

Comment: Synchro - got it working by adding

Comment: Synchro - got it working by adding
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
var_dump($_SESSION['error']);
include_once 'includes/mailer.php';
   at the bottom of my register.php code
   and adding this to the mailer.php
$_SESSION['error'] = $error;
if(empty($error)){
    BUT - it all works and throws these (2) errors
Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home1/wallace/public_html/harbour-place.com/register.php on line 203
NULL
Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home1/wallace/public_html/harbour-place.com/includes/mailer.php on line 13
NULL

Comment: So make sure your variables are defined before you try to use them? Define `$error = false;` early on in your script.