# Modal doesn't validate with PHP

Tags: php, validation, bootstrap-modal

Modal will not trigger my PHP validation.
I can't get my modal to use my PHP validation. HTML validation works. It connects to the DB and makes the updates, but skips the server-side validation. I would appreciate any help, this is new to me why a modal won't validate.

My PHP and Modal form is in one file. I know I need more error messages added to my form, but leaving the phone number and first name out triggers no error messages, so I will add more once I fix this issue. The code just executes and changes the DB.

```
       <?php
//ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
//error_reporting( E_ALL );
session_start();

  // Include db config
require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';




  // Process form when post submit
// if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // Sanitize POST
    $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $error=array();
//    $error = false;
//    $error = isset($_SESSION['error']);
//      $error = $_SESSION['error'];

    function test_input($data)
    {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

    $first  = test_input($_POST['first']);
    $last   = test_input($_POST['last']);
    $email  = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $unit   = $_SESSION['unit'];
    $bed    = test_input($_POST['bed']);
    $bath   = test_input($_POST['bath']);
    $web    = test_input($_POST['web']);
    $phone  = test_input($_POST['phone']);
    $manage = test_input($_POST['manage']);
    $ck         = $_POST['rent'];
    $id     = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Validate name
    if(empty($first) || empty($last)){
      $error['name'] = "Enter name";
    }

    // Validate email
    if(empty($email)){
      $error['email'] = "Please enter email";
      }
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error['email'] = "Invalid email format";
    }
        // Validate name
    if(empty($bed) || empty($bath)){
      $error['rooms'] = 'Please enter bed/bath #';
    }
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$web)) {
        $error['web'] = "Invalid URL";
      }
    // Validate name
    if(empty($phone)){
    $error['phone'] = 'Please enter your phone';
  }
    //Check phone # format 000-000-0000
    if(!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone)) {
      $error['phone'] = 'Please enter correct phone format';
  }
    //Check manage format
    if (!preg_match("/^(\s\(([^)]+)\))?[[:punct:]]?\p{Lu}+(?:[\s'-]?[\p{L}\d]+)+(\(([^)]+)\))*$/", $manage)) {
      $error['manage'] = 'Please enter correct management format';
  }

  if (empty($error)) {
    var_dump($error);
    print_r($error);

   $sql = 'UPDATE condos_hp SET user_firstname=:first, user_lastname=:last, user_email=:email, user_bed=:bed, user_bath=:bath, user_web=:web, user_phone=:phone, user_manage=:manage, rent=:rent WHERE id=:id';

      // Prepare statement
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        // Bind params
        $stmt->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last', $last, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//        $stmt->bindParam(':unit', $unit);
        $stmt->bindParam(':bed', $bed, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':bath', $bath, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':web', $web, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':manage', $manage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rent', $ck, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute(array(':first'=>$first, ':last'=>$last, ':email'=>$email, ':bed'=>$bed, ':bath'=>$bath, ':web'=>$web, ':phone'=>$phone, ':manage'=>$manage, ':rent'=>$ck, ':id'=>$id));


//        if($stmt){
//   header('Location: index1.php');
//}

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
//     session_start();
      //Then delete all SESSION variables
     session_unset();
      //And destroy the current session that is running
      session_destroy();
    //  exit(header("Location: http://www.harbour-place.com/login0.php?update=success"));

        if (headers_sent()) {
    die("Redirect failed. Please click on this link: <a href=http://www.harbour-place.com/login0.php>");
}
else{
   exit(header("Location: http://www.harbour-place.com/login0.php?update=success"));
}
}
}

include_once 'includes/mailer2.php';
?>


    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
   UPDATE
   </button>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userupdateform" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">UPDATE RENTAL UNIT # <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['unit']) ?> </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
              <div class="form-row justify-content-center">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label >First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm <?php echo (!empty($error['name'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" name="first" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['first']) ?>">
              <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['name']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label >Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="last" value=<?php echo  htmlentities($_SESSION['last']) ?> required>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
              <label >Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"  name="email" value=<?php echo    htmlentities($_SESSION['email']) ?> required>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label >Unit</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="unit" value=<php echo   $_SESSION['u_unit'] ?> required>
            </div>-->
          </div>
                <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label >Bed</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="bed" value=<?php echo   htmlentities($_SESSION['bed']) ?> required>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label >Bath</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="bath" value=<?php echo  htmlentities($_SESSION['bath']) ?> required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label >Web Site - www.myunit.com</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"  name="web"  value=<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['web']) ?> required>
           </div>
              </div>
          <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label >Phone 000-000-0000</label>
                  <input type="text" id="yourphone2" class="form-control form-control-sm <?php echo (!empty($error['phone'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" name="phone" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['phone']) ?>">
              <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $error['phone']; ?></span>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
              <label >Managment Co (VRBO, Self,etc)</label>
              <input type="text-capitalize" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="manage" value="<?php echo htmlentities(  $_SESSION['manage']) ?>" required>
                </div>  </div>
            <!--<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                  <label >Managment Co - VRBO etc.</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="manage" value="" required>
                </div></div>-->
              <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
             <input type="hidden" name="rent" value="0">
             <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="rent" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" checked="checked">
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check to show on the rental site</label>
             </div></div>
            <p class="text-center mb-1"><small><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Your Information is Safe With us!<br> You will need to re-login after clicking Update<br>This also updates the HP rental website listing. </small></p>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="update">UPDATE HP UNIT</button>
            </form>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you expect it to validate anything. You never check if you error array consists of any errors, and just keep running you code inserting to the database.

Comment: ^ `if (!empty($error)) { ... handle validation error` Prior to the inserts, not just too cue in the user to the error.

Comment: Why are you setting the `$error` variable three times? First as an empty array. On the next row, as `false` and then again on the next row, as the result of `isset()` (which will also be a boolean)?

Comment: You should probably also remove your `test_input()`-function. There's no need to strip anything since you're using prepared statements. Plus, you shouldn't encode the data when you save it. You should save it as is and encode it when you output it.

Comment: I added   if (empty($error)) {.....} at the bottom of all the validation. The validation is showing up now in the form, but sometimes I have to reload the modal twice to see it, When I fill-in the requested error fields now it doesn't update the DB. Thanks for the above answers, at least the errors are showing. 
Synchro suggested to add the $error = false; in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227213/phpmailer-sends-mail-with-form-errors?noredirect=1#comment89889490_51227213)
Still Stuck, but better.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson  It would help me if you could expand on error array or demo how I should do the error array??? The isset part - I thought would help me with the PHPmailer part, but maybe I should just use  $error = $_SESSION['error']; to get my error array over to my PHPmailer code.

Comment: I edited the code above - to what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here

1. You are setting $error to a boolean value, trying to define an array key with a value on a boolean doesn't work, it will continue to just be a boolean [Edit] if the value of $error evaluates to false before assigning array key => values to it, it will convert to an array but if it evaluates to true it will result in `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array` and continue to be a boolean
2. You are never checking $error to stop the script from executing and updating the database

Comment: Your first point is actually wrong. It will automatically be converted to an array.

Comment: Tested before commenting (PHP 7) 
$error = true;
$error['foo'] = 'something';
var_dump($error);

results in bool(true)

Comment: Look here: https://3v4l.org/ogGVk (that tests it with PHP 5.6 - PHP 7.3 alpha)- It does work. That's PHP's magic type juggling.

Comment: Ah I see, interesting. if the variable is true beforehand it doesn't convert if it is false it converts

Comment: Exactly. It's pretty ugly and doesn't make much sense to define it as false and then use it as an array, though. But it does work. PHP's type juggling isn't always obvious.

Comment: Synchro suggested for me to use $error = false; See link above in my comment.